# Orange "invalid flags for attribute x"

Tags: orange

I am trying to import my tab delimited data set in Orange Canvas via File widget. For some reason, I keep getting this error `invalid flags for attribute x`. I could not find anything related on web or Orange documentation. 
Can someone clarify what is actually wrong?

Data (attribute `x` is of `string`):

```
id  age gender  x
d   d   d   d
            class
1   22  M   x_val1
2   28  M   x_val2
3   18  F   x_val3
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mark an attribute as `class` if it's not.  But you still need to adhere to a [three-line format](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.data.formats.html#tab-delimited) if you want to supply feature type information (`discrete`) in the second row. With a three-line format, the third line consists of various flags ("**c**lass"; "**m**eta" (just an annotation; not used for learning); "**i**gnore" completely skipped; and possibly others).
If you add a third row of all `\t`-separated blanks, I can load it fine.

```
id  age gender  x
d   d   d   d

1   22  M   x_val1
2   28  M   x_val2
3   18  F   x_val3
```

Comment: ahh.. of course. I was a bit mislead thinking the file cannot contain all whitespace lines. Thank you and JanezD for your time and knowledge-sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Flags are in the third row of the .tab file; they tell that the attribute is, for instance, a class attribute or a meta attribute.

Can you tell us what do you have in the third row of the column for attribute x? Or show us the entire first three lines if they are not too long?

Comment: I managed to figure that out and import data without an error, but I had to add `class` tag under attribute x. Since I have unsupervised data, I don't think this is the right way. I have edited my original question with a few lines of shorten data.